# how to get values in GridView using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I access a value in a GridView, in this case i have a `target_date` in there and would like to get that value and convert it to string. Here is what I have:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows)
{
   CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("chkItem");
   if (cb.Checked)
   {
      string strTargetDate = "???"; // TODO
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code :

```
foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows)
{
   var cells = gr.Cells;
   CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("chkItem");
   if (cb.Checked)
   {
      string strTargetDate = cells[0].Text;
   }
}
```

Comment: it says the name cells does not exist

Comment: @moe  use `gr.Cells[0].Text`

Answer (score 0):

The must be something like
GridView1.Rows[(int)rowIndex].Cells[(int)ColIndex].Value;
or
GridView1.Rows[(int)rowIndex].Cells[(string)ColName].Value;